# Magmi's Datapump API Update changes nothing, Create works fine

Tags: magmi

The two code examples that they provide for the API both involve creating new products. I've gotten this to work fine, creating hundreds of thousands of new products with it with no issues.

Now when it comes time to update something (via either update or create mode), for example mass updating a bunch of product's visibility, or their image, nothing happens. It says it successfully runs, but none of the changes actually happen. Is there anything different that you need to do to update an existing product? Here's one example of what I would run:

```
$dp=Magmi_DataPumpFactory::getDataPumpInstance("productimport");  
$dp->beginImportSession("test_ptj","update",new TestLogger());  
$product=array("sku"=>$productsku,"visibility"=>"Catalog");
$dp->ingest($product);
$dp->endImportSession();
```

That doesn't work on any products I run it through though. Logger says it updated them, but it's not reflected when I view the products in the back-end (after indexing). Any ideas?

Comment: the first idea is that they already have "visibility" assigned per store (if they were earlier imported with "store" column), and the snippet you give is defaulting to "admin" store. So it's a "lower" level, that's why it might be overwritten with per-store values.

Comment: Doh! Ok, that makes sense, what should I be using for "store" then when creating/updating to make sure that overrides the default? I just realized that this wasn't working on my create either, so that explains a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you do `"visibility" => "Catalog"`, try  `"visibility" => 2` instead. The possible reason is that it doesn't map text to real option value for the drop-down attribute.

i.e.

```
1 = Not Visible Individually
2 = Catalog
3 = Search
4 = Catalog, Search
```

Comment: That was it, I guess I incorrectly assumed that it was using the same values as magento import/export. Also, coincidentally the only other time I tried "updating" from Magmi was using images that turns out it just didn't like, making me think it was Magmi's update function.

Comment: you can install "Generic Mapper" plugin which makes possible to have text format for this field and other "dropdown" fields like "Status" (Enabled/Disabled) etc. Otherwise you need to assign numeric index values for those attributes.